# how to filter and map json file into html?

Tags: javascript, html, json, mapping

I use the below code to filter the json file.

```
<script>fetch("workers.json")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => console.log(json.filter(function(item){
return item.name == "sam"; })));
```

How to map this filtered output into html file?

My json file.

```
[{
"name": "sam",
"age": "26",
"salary": "20000",
"portfolio": "https://www.example.com/1"},{
"name": "tony",
"age": "30",
"salary": "30000",
"portfolio": "https://www.example.com/2" },{
"name": "sam",
"age": "24",
"salary": "15000",
"portfolio": "https://www.example.com/3"}]
```

required output:

name:sam

age:24

portfolio:https://www.example.com/3

salary:15000

name:sam

age:26

portfolio:https://www.example.com/1

salary:20000

Answer (score 0):

I've done this two ways in the past. The first (and easier of the two) is to use a templating engine. The second, and more difficult, is to use a frontend framework like React.js or Angular.js. I'll go over the first because it's a lot easier. React.js involves using JSX and Angular involves using TypeScript so those are nontrivial solutions.

For using a templating engine.

1. First, you would need to install pug, handlebars, ejs, or any templating engine of your choice. To do this, type in npm install  and import it into your app.js file (or wherever the entry point in your package.json file is).

The code for setting your templating engine will look something like:

```js
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

2. Use a translator to translate your html code to the code of the templating engine of your choice. Personally, when I use templating engines, I use pug, so a great tool for translation is: https://html2jade.org/. Once you have your pug file, what you're going to want to do is inject variables into it. For example, if you want to change the title of the page dynamically you could say: title #{title}.
3. Save your pug file into your views folder.
4. In your viewController, write some code that to render your page. For example, in one of my last projects, my code for fetching a login page looked something like:

```js
exports.getLoginForm = (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .set(
      'Content-Security-Policy',
      "connect-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
    )
    .render('login', {
      title: 'Login',
    });
};
```

res.status(200) sends the success http code, and .render chained to it renders the file 'login', which is a pug file. Within the options object, the key-value pair title: 'Login' is passed. *This is where you can insert your dynamic data.* Now, in the pug file you created, when it is loaded, 'Login' will begin the title of the page. As stated before, you can implement variables throughout your pug code using the same #{variableName} syntax I mentioned above. Therefore, your final code, (if written in pug) could something like:

p #{name} p #{age} p #{portfolio}.

where name, age, and portfolio would be changed depending on the parameters you specify in your render object.

5. Next you're going to have to implement a route in your viewRoutes file, or whatever you chose to name it, and implement a route like:

```js
router.get('/login', authController.isLoggedIn, viewsController.getLoginForm);
```

Now, it should work, since you have a route, view, and controller. Since you're importing data from a JSON file, you're probably not thinking about having a dedicated model or schema in a database like MongoDB. However, the important part is that you can use the object in the render function to pass custom options.

I don't know what your backend looks like, but this is one possible solution that follows the MVC architecture.

If you have any questions or criticism please let me know below. I would be happy to clarify anything further.